# Typescript spread operator causing object to be treated as a string

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm reasonably new to typescript and I have been attempting to create a DAO for DynamoDB to insert objects into a table. However, when using the spread operator it appears to cause the object to be split into individual characters instead.

My method simply takes the object, adds a few fields to it via the spread operator and then inserts it into the table. From my understanding this should work however as you can see by the `console.log()` before and after the spread operation on the 'itemToInsert' something is going wrong.

**The Method**

```
async createItem(item: FleetAccount): Promise<FleetAccount> {
        console.log(item);

        const itemToInsert: FleetAccount = {
            ...item,
            id: generateUniqueKey("ACC"),
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),

        };

        console.log(itemToInsert);

        try {
            await this.docClient.send(new PutCommand({
                TableName: this.tableName,
                Item: itemToInsert,
                ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(id)'
            }));
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof ConditionalCheckFailedException) { //Error when the item already exists.
                return Promise.reject("Item with specified Id already exists.");
            } else {
                console.log("FAILURE!");
                console.log(e);
                return Promise.reject();
            }
        }

        return itemToInsert;
    }
```

**The Interface/Type**

```
export default interface FleetAccount {
    id: string;
    businessName:
    businessAddress: string;
    abn: string;
    primaryContactId: string;
    invoiceIds: Array<string>;
    availableMerchants: Array<string>;
    requireVehicleRegistration: boolean; 
    users: Array<string>;
    createdAt:
    updatedAt: string;
}
```

**Item**

```
{
"businessName": "Test Company",
"businessAddress": "123 Fake Street, Canberra, Australia, 2903",
"abn": "123456",
"primaryContactId": "FUI1234",
"invoiceIds": ["1"],
"availableMerchants": ["1"],
"requireVehicleRegistration": false,
"users": ["1"]
}
```

**itemToInsert**

```
{
  '0': '{',
  '1': '\r',
  '2': '\n',
  '3': ' ',
  '4': ' ',
  '5': ' ',
  '6': ' ',
  '7': '"',
  '8': 'b',
  '9': 'u',
  '10': 's',
  '11': 'i',
  '12': 'n',
  '13': 'e',
  '14': 's',
  '15': 's',
  '16': 'N',
  '17': 'a',
  '18': 'm',
  '19': 'e',
  '20': '"',
  '21': ':',
  '22': ' ',
  '23': '"',
  '24': 'T',
  '25': 'e',
  '26': 's',
  '27': 't',
  '28': ' ',
  '29': 'C',
  '30': 'o',
  '31': 'm',
  '32': 'p',
  '33': 'a',
  '34': 'n',
  '35': 'y',
  '36': '"',
  '37': ',',
  '38': '\r',
  '39': '\n',
  '40': ' ',
  '41': ' ',
  '42': ' ',
  '43': ' ',
  '44': '"',
  '45': 'b',
  '46': 'u',
  '47': 's',
  '48': 'i',
  '49': 'n',
  '50': 'e',
  '51': 's',
  '52': 's',
  '53': 'A',
  '54': 'd',
  '55': 'd',
  '56': 'r',
  '57': 'e',
  '58': 's',
  '59': 's',
  '60': '"',
  '61': ':',
  '62': ' ',
  '63': '"',
  '64': '1',
  '65': '2',
  '66': '3',
  '67': ' ',
  '68': 'F',
  '69': 'a',
  '70': 'k',
  '71': 'e',
  '72': ' ',
  '73': 'S',
  '74': 't',
  '75': 'r',
  '76': 'e',
  '77': 'e',
  '78': 't',
  '79': ',',
  '80': ' ',
  '81': 'C',
  '82': 'a',
  '83': 'n',
  '84': 'b',
  '85': 'e',
  '86': 'r',
  '87': 'r',
  '88': 'a',
  '89': ',',
  '90': ' ',
  '91': 'A',
  '92': 'u',
  '93': 's',
  '94': 't',
  '95': 'r',
  '96': 'a',
  '97': 'l',
  '98': 'i',
  '99': 'a',
  '100': ',',
  '101': ' ',
  '102': '2',
  '103': '9',
  '104': '0',
  '105': '3',
  '106': '"',
  '107': ',',
  '108': '\r',
  '109': '\n',
  '110': ' ',
  '111': ' ',
  '112': ' ',
  '113': ' ',
  '114': '"',
  '115': 'a',
  '116': 'b',
  '117': 'n',
  '118': '"',
  '119': ':',
  '120': ' ',
  '121': '"',
  '122': '1',
  '123': '2',
  '124': '3',
  '125': '4',
  '126': '5',
  '127': '6',
  '128': '"',
  '129': ',',
  '130': '\r',
  '131': '\n',
  '132': ' ',
  '133': ' ',
  '134': ' ',
  '135': ' ',
  '136': '"',
  '137': 'p',
  '138': 'r',
  '139': 'i',
  '140': 'm',
  '141': 'a',
  '142': 'r',
  '143': 'y',
  '144': 'C',
  '145': 'o',
  '146': 'n',
  '147': 't',
  '148': 'a',
  '149': 'c',
  '150': 't',
  '151': 'I',
  '152': 'd',
  '153': '"',
  '154': ':',
  '155': ' ',
  '156': '"',
  '157': 'F',
  '158': 'U',
  '159': 'I',
  '160': '1',
  '161': '2',
  '162': '3',
  '163': '4',
  '164': '"',
  '165': ',',
  '166': '\r',
  '167': '\n',
  '168': ' ',
  '169': ' ',
  '170': ' ',
  '171': ' ',
  '172': '"',
  '173': 'i',
  '174': 'n',
  '175': 'v',
  '176': 'o',
  '177': 'i',
  '178': 'c',
  '179': 'e',
  '180': 'I',
  '181': 'd',
  '182': 's',
  '183': '"',
  '184': ':',
  '185': ' ',
  '186': '[',
  '187': '"',
  '188': '1',
  '189': '"',
  '190': ']',
  '191': ',',
  '192': '\r',
  '193': '\n',
  '194': ' ',
  '195': ' ',
  '196': ' ',
  '197': ' ',
  '198': '"',
  '199': 'a',
  '200': 'v',
  '201': 'a',
  '202': 'i',
  '203': 'l',
  '204': 'a',
  '205': 'b',
  '206': 'l',
  '207': 'e',
  '208': 'M',
  '209': 'e',
  '210': 'r',
  '211': 'c',
  '212': 'h',
  '213': 'a',
  '214': 'n',
  '215': 't',
  '216': 's',
  '217': '"',
  '218': ':',
  '219': ' ',
  '220': '[',
  '221': '"',
  '222': '1',
  '223': '"',
  '224': ']',
  '225': ',',
  '226': '\r',
  '227': '\n',
  '228': ' ',
  '229': ' ',
  '230': ' ',
  '231': ' ',
  '232': '"',
  '233': 'r',
  '234': 'e',
  '235': 'q',
  '236': 'u',
  '237': 'i',
  '238': 'r',
  '239': 'e',
  '240': 'V',
  '241': 'e',
  '242': 'h',
  '243': 'i',
  '244': 'c',
  '245': 'l',
  '246': 'e',
  '247': 'R',
  '248': 'e',
  '249': 'g',
  '250': 'i',
  '251': 's',
  '252': 't',
  '253': 'r',
  '254': 'a',
  '255': 't',
  '256': 'i',
  '257': 'o',
  '258': 'n',
  '259': '"',
  '260': ':',
  '261': ' ',
  '262': 'f',
  '263': 'a',
  '264': 'l',
  '265': 's',
  '266': 'e',
  '267': ',',
  '268': '\r',
  '269': '\n',
  '270': ' ',
  '271': ' ',
  '272': ' ',
  '273': ' ',
  '274': '"',
  '275': 'u',
  '276': 's',
  '277': 'e',
  '278': 'r',
  '279': 's',
  '280': '"',
  '281': ':',
  '282': ' ',
  '283': '[',
  '284': '"',
  '285': '1',
  '286': '"',
  '287': ']',
  '288': '\r',
  '289': '\n',
  '290': '}',
  id: 'ACCBPNEJB84SMJJHFA',
  createdAt: '2023-11-18T14:24:38.256Z',
  updatedAt: '2023-11-18T14:24:38.256Z'
}
```

Is there another way that these fields should be added to this object to make it more clear to JS that this is not a string? I have already tried `Object.assign()` with the same result.

Comment: In addition to logging the object values, it is a good idea to log a message to indicate what follows (so you can tell one debug message from another), and also to log the type: `console.log("Item: type is " + (typeof item)); console.dir(item);`

Comment: Are you sure that `item` variable is an actual object and not a `string`? Asking because code like `const x = JSON.stringify({a: 10, b: 20});
console.log({...x})` will produce the result similar to yours.

Comment: Also, to be pedantic for a moment, "spread" is not an *operator*; it is not part of the expression grammar.

Comment: I second @SergeySosunov: `console.log` of an object produces indentation and unquoted property names. Your `console.log(item)` looks different.

Comment: @SergeySosunov As I come from a Java background my assumption was that as I specified the type in the method it was going to be that type. However, I know that typescript is just javascript at runtime so that is a very good point. In the calling method it is specified as an Any type which could be part of the issue. I guess this is why people use fp-ts and io-ts in projects to ensure typing at runtime

Comment: @Pointy as you pointed out with the `typeof` the object is a string. Evidently, things are busted in the calling method and not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens if you spread a string.

For example, take this piece of code,

```js
const myObject = {
    ..."Random String",
}

console.log(myObject)
```

The output is

```
{
  "0": "R",
  "1": "a",
  "2": "n",
  "3": "d",
  "4": "o",
  "5": "m",
  "6": " ",
  "7": "S",
  "8": "t",
  "9": "r",
  "10": "i",
  "11": "n",
  "12": "g"
}
```

Can you verify that the value in the variable item of type FleetAccount is actually FleetAccount and not a String?

You could do something like and see if it prints string.

```js
console.log(typeof(item))
```

The variable item here

```js
async createItem(item: FleetAccount): Promise<FleetAccount> {
  ...
}
```

could hold a string value in Typescript even though you explicitly state it to be of type FleetAccount, since Typescript is just a compile time checker for Javascript which does not have the concept of types, ie, types are not enforced at runtime.

Comment: Note that `typeof` is an operator not a function, you don't need the parens.

Comment: This was exactly what was occurring. I needed to `JSON.parse()` the string from the Lambda body before passing it to this method. Silly mistake coming from a strongly typed language background.

Comment: @EzzyC yes, IMO JSON.parse should return `unknown` but they return `any` which is unfortunate. You can opt into the stricter behavior with something [like this](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset). I'm surprised it didn't complain about you passing a string where something else was expected tho

Comment: @JaredSmith That seems very useful thank you! I have looked into fp-ts and io-ts previously but that is a rather intense solution to the typing issues faced in Typescript.

Comment: @EzzyC yeah I made mistakes like that too while starting out with Typescript lol.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like working for me [link to check playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ0g2CmAuwMYCdIENqQJJoLbALzAAoBLbALmAHkAjAK0jmgEo8A%20AKDDAG8PO%204A9gDsAzrBKQsAFQHpRkBLFy8%203Far4A6bRKwAadRrCIUaACYBBaOSGQA7sAAiqSAUabosgMoUv0BERCAOZuBkaqAK4ADmYultbAtg7OaG4e3r7%20gSGMBoaqAL4A3Gz5fEjQEQhCwLoyciIK0CUaBaUaULBB4AJUyOCYknhlwDwaAERUESKBkCIiAHLIWJDj5ONSc7AAwgJYUchCAJ7jYaqT07PzFmZmSPNrwOMAjABMAMzAAGLIANaQwD8SBgemA20OVAUCGQoIs038-SIMOArwAnAAGd6nEbjZBUISPF4fAAsAFYAGzYiZRAJYZAII67ITQZAMdBmQlfACq6De72JVPOgQAbgIiHAMGYRI8ANovcYAXTOfFxwuQRHAeKgAFkFHAABaHaDS8hy56K5WccZIACOESISAAapB9eKoAAlSBBIhiaHQIjCR4AM36jUtYHG0wUJuAZsVIzaI0CaAQIYlwAA4j0%20gNsEyg0QgiMxuFamZyL7si1S1MZrZ5ksVuRDkdq%20Fa1cRDc7nMRBWssE20Y8UJ%20wFByMwDSiHSGUyWWzy8BKxPS7UhKLxZK%208ALAhoUcADwroIsIcaZBqjVayC6hAGo07vcH48D0-n1S2%201Ol1uyCe71fVQANR2AKgBAEKBDiKYBJ1AKMECffdkCPE8zzgkATDiKwxyrDDgGiWJzBw5c3w-EBinaVROngPYogicxBiwcgs16fomPzQsShGQR9gYyAzCYvB4CQFwmIIbo2NzSRmGQERM2zdi82EAsgm4jRBFESDIE0HoQl4%20jGOwRgiiAA)

```typescript
let createItem = (item: Object) =>
{
    const itemToInsert =
    {
        ...item,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),

    };

    return itemToInsert;
}

let globalItem =
{
  "businessName": "Test Company",
  "businessAddress": "123 Fake Street, Canberra, Australia, 2903",
  "abn": "123456",
  "primaryContactId": "FUI1234",
  "invoiceIds": ["1"],
  "availableMerchants": ["1"],
  "requireVehicleRegistration": false,
  "users": ["1"]
};

interface GlobalItemConfig
{
    id: string;
    businessName: any;
    businessAddress: string;
    abn: string;
    primaryContactId: string;
    invoiceIds: Array<string>;
    availableMerchants: Array<string>;
    requireVehicleRegistration: boolean; 
    users: Array<string>;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
};

let computedItem: GlobalItemConfig;

computedItem = createItem(globalItem) as GlobalItemConfig;

console.log(computedItem);
```